# How can I use the host's DNS resolver from a Hyper-V VM with an internal switch?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, dns, hyper-v

I have two network connections on the host: one to the internet and a VPN one.
The VPN one has a DNS resolver bound to 127.50.100.1 which I cannot configure. And since this is a loopback address I cannot specify it from a VM.

Hyper-V's default switch gives NAT, DHCP and access to the host's DNS resolver. But it's IP is randomized on each reboot. So I'd like to use an internal switch with fix IP. But the internal switch doesn't provide any of these. I can configure NAT using the Powershell's New-NetNat command, but I still don't have DNS and DHCP. I can live without DHCP as I can assign addresses manually. But I need the host's DNS resolver to resolve intranet addresses trough the host's loopback dns server. How can I do that?

The current workaround is having both the default and internal switch but I don't like that.

(host = Management OS over Hyper-V. It's shorter to write just host)